# Copying store view image settings to the default settings

Tags: php, image, magento

In Magento (1.9.2) I have successfully imported a load of products and their images.

In the admin panel, if I select a product, and then select a store view, I can see that the product images are all correctly loaded as thumbnail, base image and small image.

However if I select a product and don't select a store view (keeping it on admin/default values) the images are there, but the thumbnail, base image and small image are all set to nothing.

How can I copy over the store view image settings to the default image settings for the entire product catalog?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to look at a different store view, and then everything became clear.